# How to pass args and template_fields to dataproc from airflow 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to execute python code on a dataproc cluster via airflow orchestration.

I am using **airflow 1.10.12**, and `DataprocWorkflowTemplateInstantiateInlineOperator` to instanciate a **dataproc** cluster & pass some parameters (and templated params aswell). The main objective is to run some prediction code.

Note that I upgraded this code so use **`airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc`** and not **`airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator`** to import `DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator`, because the former introduced the `parameters` kwarg that, in theory, permits passing arguments to the cluster. Using the later in my other scripts, I have no errors, but I cannot introduce parameters to the cluster.

```
...
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import (
    DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator,
)
...

workflow_seg_members = make_workflow_template(
    region=REGION,
    dataproc_job_bucket=DATAPROC_JOB_BUCKET,
    python_main_executable_path="segmentation_members/seg_members_prediction.py",
)

op_seg_members_prediction = DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator(
    task_id="seg_members_prediction",
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=REGION,
    template=workflow_seg_members,
    parameters={
        "execution_date_str": "{{ds_nodash}}",
        "project": "<REDACTED>",
        "dataset": "<REDACTED>",
        "features_table_prefix": "global_features",
        "output_table_prefix": "seg_members_output",
        "path_to_model": "segmentation_members/DecisionTreeClassifier.pkl",
        "bucket_name": "<REDACTED>",
        "model_designation": "Segmentation Members",
    },
)
```

in `seg_members_prediction.py`, I use `argparse` to create the needed arguments.

The error I am getting is :

```
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2.OrderedJob got str.
```

My questions are :

- <s>How do I fix this `MergeFrom()` exception?</s>
- Is this the right approach to pass parameters from airflow to my dataproc cluster?

Here is the complete stack :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 373, in inner_wrapper
  return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataproc.py", line 712, in instantiate_inline_workflow_template
  metadata=metadata,
File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/gapic/workflow_template_service_client.py", line 488, in instantiate_inline_workflow_template
  request_id=request_id,
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2.OrderedJob got str.
[2022-06-13 12:36:34,696] {taskinstance.py:1197} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=ds_seg_members_integration, task_id=seg_members_prediction, execution_date=20220610T162234, start_date=20220613T123629, end_date=20220613T123634
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 7, in <module>
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 561, in run
    _run(args, dag, ti)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 480, in _run
    pool=args.pool,
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 986, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 1748, in execute
    metadata=self.metadata,
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 373, in inner_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataproc.py", line 712, in instantiate_inline_workflow_template
    metadata=metadata,
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/gapic/workflow_template_service_client.py", line 488, in instantiate_inline_workflow_template
    request_id=request_id,
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2.OrderedJob got str.
```

EDIT :

I tried running the following code but still got the same error :

```
op_seg_members_prediction = DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator(
    task_id="seg_members_prediction",
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=REGION,
    template=workflow_seg_members,
)

op_seg_members_prediction.execute(context="DEBUG")
```

After browsing the [**apache-airflow-providers-google** doc](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/) I discovered it isn't compatible with **airflow 1**.

> You can install this package on top of an existing Airflow 2
> installation (see Requirements below for the minimum Airflow version
> supported) via pip install apache-airflow-providers-google
>
> The package supports the following python versions: 3.7,3.8,3.9,3.10

So I upgraded to **airflow 2** in my local environment, and the `MergeFrom()` error stopped occurring.

This still begs the question : How do you pass parameters from airflow to dataproc for **airflow 1**

Comment: What happens if you set for example `"execution_date_str": "2019-08-02"`?

Comment: @EladKalif same error